# Find the infinum and supremum of the set E.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Let $$E = \{x \mid 3x^2 - 10x + 3 < 0\}.$$ Find $\sup{E}$ and $\inf{E}$.

Where do I start this proof?

Comment: think f '(x) <0 and then find the root,,

Answer (score 4):

We have:
$$3x^2 -10+3 <0$$
factorising:
$$(3x-1)(x-3)<0.$$
This tells us that $\frac13 < x< 3$. I'll leave the rest to you.